# Need help to make a func such as ('a -> 'b) option -> 'a option -> 'b option

Tags: ocaml

I'm currently learning Ocaml on my cursus and i've been trying to solve this exercise for a long time, but I can't for the life of me find the answer..

How do i make a function that applies an optional function to an optional value, and if one of these is missing, we return None.

```
val apply_opt : ('a -> 'b) option -> 'a option -> 'b option
```

I hope you guys can help me cause i can't find any example of this

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far, and try to explain why you're struggling? The point of an exercise is usually that you should try to figure it out yourself, so just giving you the answer won't really help you.

Comment: Hey, well i was trying to do it and my teacher gave me some hints and he said and  what i wrote so far is true :    ' let apply_opt a b =
  match a with
  | None -> None
  | Some x ->
      match b with
      | None -> None
      | Some y ->             '                                                                                               He wouldn't tell me next and i can't see the answer :(

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is nearly there, you just didn't finish the last bit. It could be simplified by matching against `a,b` and using the catchall `_`, eg.

```
let apply_opt a b =
  match a,b with
  | Some f, Some x -> Some (f x)
  | _ -> None
```

Comment: Please do not give a complete answer to a class assignment.